# Accessible Bootstrap Accordion inside Dropdown

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, wai-aria

I have implemented a few accordions following Bootstrap's recommended markup but it's not fully compliant with ARIA. I'm looking into having something like this:

http://oaa-accessibility.org/examplep/accordian1/

However, when I hit tab and the arrow, space and enter keyboard keys, the behaviour is not the expected. Bootstrap doesn't handle key events and some aria attributes are missing and/or not updated properly (i.e. aria-selected, tabindex)

I have tried integrating the JavaScript code in the accessible example but I think it's not quite as smooth as I would like.

I have this codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWWewr

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default"> ... here goes the panel-heading
  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne"> ... here goes the panel contents
  </div>
</div>
```

A couple questions:

1. First time trying to show (press space bar or enter keys) in second and last panels, don't open on the first try. Maybe just a markup issue? or do I have any bugs in the code that someone can help me spot...
2. Is it possible to get this working in Bootstrap without having this special script and just specifying aria compliant markup?
3. If the answer is no, what would be the best way to convert this into a plugin for Bootstrap? can anyone point me into the right path into writing Bootstrap plugins?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just found an old closed issue in bootstrap - https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/14295 - apparently it'll be resolved in v4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, there's an issue with your HTML markup and the TablPanel.togglePanel() code.

togglePanel() receives the tab (div.panel-heading) and then looks at the children panels. (div.panel-collapse)  It checks the "aria-hidden" attribute and if it's true (the panel is hidden), then set it to false. (show the panel)

However, in your markup, all the div.panel-collapse's have aria-hidden undefined, so tabPanel assumes they are visible and hides them, setting aria-hidden=true.  (The second click then finds aria-hidden 'cuz now it's been set, and it sets it to false and shows the panel)

Set aria-hidden=true on your unopened div.panel-collpase's and then things should be fine. :)

As for the rest, I don't believe you can do what you're looking for using Bootstrap/aria mark-up alone, the Boostrap JS code for the accordion behaviour (collapse.js) doesn't implement aria-selected, aria-hidden or keyboard listeners, so you'd have to write a plugin.  Which, alas, I have never done. :/